# Plotly.js adds top-margin to graphs inconsistently, how to prevent it

Tags: javascript, matlab, plotly

With Plotly.js I'm getting a top-margin added sometimes (not consistently), where the total height of the graph is 300px, but the graph itself is only 150px high. The SVG container then is stretched and the actual graph is smaller. What can I do to prevent this white-space, and why does it only show up selectively?

[image: Margin above graph]

Plotly Matlab syntax that results in 300px div instead of a 300px graph:

```
`% PLOT MEAN MOVEMENT
    data = {...
      struct(...
        'x', nScan, ...
        'y',fastmotion, ...
         'type', 'scatter')...
         };
    if max(fastmotion) < 0.3
        yminval = 0.3;
    else
        yminval = round(max(fastmotion) + 1);
    end
    layout = struct(...
    'yaxis', struct(...
    'title', 'Movement (mm)', ...
    'range', [0, yminval]));
    header{3} = 'Absolute Movement';
    layout.width = 800;
    layout.height = 300;
    p = plotlyfig; 
    p.data = data;
    p.layout = layout;
    p.PlotOptions.FileName = 'plot_5';
    html_file = plotlyoffline(p);
    html_file;`
```

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB? I suggest you post your code (and not in a picture!)

Comment: It has to do with the Plotly.js library, but I've used Matlab to send it to a HTML file. The question however is about the Plotly.js library.

Answer (score 8):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406525/plotly-js-remove-title-and-title-area) on a different question, and here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6e8fhqn/2/).

**The quick code you can use:**

```
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 20,
    r: 20,
    b: 20,
    t: 20,
    pad: 5
  }, title: false
};
```

As `mfedoten` says on his answer: `But be careful if you have tick labels, if you set margins to zero the labels will be cropped`

Answer (score 0):

So apparently line 68 in plotlyfig.m caused the issue:

```
obj.PlotlyDefaults.MinTitleMargin = 80;
```

Even though I had no title, it sometimes added 80 px on top of the graph, maxing out at the specified graph height. Setting this value to 0 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably line 68 in plotlyfig.m just set default margins.

You can set the margins manually like that:

`p.layout.margin = struct('b', 15,'l', 30, 'r', 0, 't', 0);`

You can find documentation on margins [here](https://plot.ly/matlab/reference/#layout-margin).

But be careful if you have tick labels, if you set margins to zero the labels will be cropped.