# plotly js remove title and title area

Tags: javascript, plotly

How does on remove the title from a plotly js chart?

Example chart I have is as follows

```
<head>
     <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

var trace1 = {
   x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
   mode: 'markers'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: 'lines+markers'
};

var data = [ trace1, trace2, trace3 ];

var layout = {
  title:false
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
</script>
```

This chart will have a title "false", I have also tried
    var layout = {
        showtitle:false
    }

setting the title to null: `title:''` or simply removing the title line, doesn't display a title, but the title area which is approxiamtely 50px in height above the chart reserved for the title remains, how do I remove this title area?

Comment: Can you pass an empty string as the title?

Comment: No, as I said in the last paragraph, while that removes the title, the area reserved for the title remains

Comment: I apologise, it's late here and I missed the last paragraph.

Comment: You can just not pass the title in the layout

Comment: Again, the area reserved for the title remains, making a big empty space of nothing.

Comment: That's a different issue, see https://plot.ly/javascript/setting-graph-size/

Comment: Also jsfiddle showing the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/v6e8fhqn/2/

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help, while that answer is so easy, I have been looking for this for hours !

Comment: We've all been there!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By removing the title from the layout config it will no longer render it. However, the margins are still configured to create the space for it. You will need to override those default margins as explained [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/setting-graph-size).

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6e8fhqn/2) showing that config applied to generate the desired output.

This is the meat of it:

```
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 50,
    r: 50,
    b: 50,
    t: 50,
    pad: 4
  }
};
```